# Why sometimes the charger for iPad Pro cannot charge for Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, battery, charger

Why sometimes the charger for iPad Pro cannot charge for Macbook Pro.

I use the charger for iPad Pro to charge Macbook Pro, sometimes it can be used to charge the Macbook Pro while sometimes it cannot work.

[image]

---

Comment: Why vote down? Is this question a bad question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chargers have different capacities.

So the ipad charger can charge the pro when it is idle but cannot meet the demand when the pro is working hard.